# How to limit aggregation of daily value into monthly and annual totals?

Tags: r, date, time-series, plyr, zoo

I have a zoo object(stn) of long records of daily data (date Vs rain). I have used hydoTSM package

(m <- daily2monthly(stn, FUN=sum,na.rm=TRUE))

which works fine but I want to allow aggregation only for months with at least 20 daily records. For annual, at least 10 months of records should be available. Can anybody suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, if using **plyr** is an option. You'd have to make your zoo object `stn` into a data frame.

```
rain <- data.frame(date=c("1987-01-01", "1987-01-02", "1987-01-03", "1988-10-01", "1988-11-02", "1988-11-01"), 
              pcp=c(2, 0.6, 1, 2.7, 1.1, 1.3)
           )

rain$Year <- 1900+as.POSIXlt(rain$date)$year
rain$Month <-1+as.POSIXlt(rain$date)$mon
rain$Day <-as.POSIXlt(rain$date)$mday

annualAgg <- function(df) {
   if(length(unique(df$Month))<10) return(NULL) #aggregate only if <10 months in that year
  mean(df$pcp)
}

monthlyRainAgg <- function(df) {
  if(length(unique(df$Day))<20) return(NULL) #aggregate monthly only if <20 days in that month
  mean(df$pcp)
}

library(plyr)
## Call the functions above using ddply
# ddply sends the functions thinly sliced df's
monthly.agg.df <- ddply(rain, .(Year, Month), monthlyRainAgg)
monthly.agg.df

annual.agg <-  ddply(rain, .(Year), annualAgg)
annual.agg
```